# How to dynamically replace values in string

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to replace a unkown amount of strings inside a string and save it in a variable.

```
var wpContent;
var sourceUrlArray = [];
var pageContent = response.d.Content    

for (var i = 0; i < sourceUrlArray.length; i++) {
         wpContent = pageContent.replace(sourceUrlArray[i].url, sourceUrlArray[i].sourceUrl)
        }
```

`pageContent` holds the string where i want to replace one or more instances of a string. The old and new values are stored in `sourceUrlArray`.

The content of the `sourceUrlArray` is dynamic and can change.

Only the last replacement is made. I know that is has something to do with it overwriting the `wpcontent` variable, but I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong here.

Comment: The value(s) might vary. So it's not a replace all.

Comment: At each loop iteration, you override the previously set value of wpContent. You need to assign `wpContent = pageContent` before the loop and on each iteration do `wpContent = wpContent.replace...`.

Comment: `var wpContent = response.d.Content; /*...*/ for(...) { wpContent = wpContent.replace(...); }`

Comment: Thanks! That did it.